# Visual Studio 2015 RC Report Data Window is missing

Tags: rdlc, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

In Visual Studio 2015 RC Report Data Window is missing. Report data menu item is not presented in View menu and  do not react on hotkey Ctrl+Alt+D. Does anyone faced with such bug? How can I open Report Data window in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in Visual Studio 2015 RTM.